Can I use an expression as gauge max value for a Graphana chart?
I have a Grafana gauge chart that shows current memory usage in bytes. As the total memory installed on the machine is also returned from a metric, so I want to use an expression as max value of the gauge instead of hard code total memory size. I tried to set machine_memory_bytes{job="cadvisor"} to the gauge's max value textbox, but that didn't work.
Is there any alternative way to that?
